# CI/CD for a Blazor web

Tags: blazor, azure-blob-storage, blazor-webassembly, azure-pipelines-build-task, azure-static-website-hosting

I want to set up CI/CD for a Blazor web client application project to copy the contents to an Azure blob storage. Below are the CI tasks

```
- task: VSBuild@1
  displayName: 'Build MyBlazor Web'
  inputs:
    solution: ./MyBlazorWeb/MyBlazorWeb.sln
    vsVersion: 16.0
    msbuildArgs: '/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:PackageLocation="$(build.artifactStagingDirectory)"'
    configuration: Release
    restoreNugetPackages: true


- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'Publishing MyBlazor Web...'
  inputs:
    command: publish
    publishWebProjects: true
    projects: ./MyBlazorWeb/MyBlazorWeb/MyBlazorWeb.csproj
    arguments: '--configuration $(BuildConfiguration) --output $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/drop/MyBlazorWeb'
    artifactName: MyBlazor
    zipAfterPublish: false

- publish: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)
  artifact: drop
```

Below is my CD task

```
- task: AzureFileCopy@2
  displayName: 'Copy MyBlazorWeb to Static Web Site'
  inputs:
    SourcePath: '$(build.artifactStagingDirectory)/drop/MyBlazorWeb'
    azureSubscription: '$(subscription)'
    Destination: AzureBlob
    storage: '$(storage-account-name)'
    ContainerName: '$web'
```

The AZCopy throws the below error

> Error parsing source location "D:\a\1\a\drop\MyBlazorWeb": Failed to enumerate directory D:\a\1\a\drop\MyBlazorWeb\ with file pattern *.
> The system cannot find the path specified. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070003) For more details, please type "AzCopy /?:Source" or use verbose option /V.

Am I missing any additional tasks or not using the correct source path? If those tasks/steps are not correct, how can I host Blazor webassembly in Azure storage?

Answer (score 2):

You can specify the `System.ArtifactsDirectory` variable in the `SourcePath` parameter of the AzureFileCopy task.

```
- task: AzureFileCopy@2
  displayName: 'Copy MyBlazorWeb to Static Web Site'
  inputs:
    SourcePath: '$(System.ArtifactsDirectory)/drop/MyBlazorWeb'
    azureSubscription: '$(subscription)'
    Destination: AzureBlob
    storage: '$(storage-account-name)'
    ContainerName: '$web'
```

`System.ArtifactsDirectory`: The directory to which artifacts are downloaded during deployment of a release. The directory is cleared before every deployment if it requires artifacts to be downloaded to the agent. Same as Agent.ReleaseDirectory and System.DefaultWorkingDirectory.
Example: `C:\agent\_work\r1\a`

`Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory` is agent-scoped variable, so you can not use it in release pipeline.